# i am having problems redirecting after a method call in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have finally got my custom def methods working and updating the table in my database but know i am having issues redirecting back to my accounts index page. it will just go to my update.html.erb page. the source of the issue mayb in my routes and/or authenication issue with cancancan/devise ? maybe my  before_filter :authenticate_user! But when i change to redirect_to accounts_url, i get this,
  Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".

my controller , the declarations at the top and my update method

```
 class AccountsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_account, only: [:show, :edit, :deposit, 
 :withdrawl,:update, :destroy]
  # before_filter :set_account, only: [:show, :edit, :deposit, :withdrawl, 
 :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  respond_to :js, :html
  #respond_to :html

  def update
    @account = Account.find(params[:id]) 
    @account.update(account_params)
    respond_with(@account)
    return accounts_url 
end
```

my routes

```
   Rails.application.routes.draw do


  # get 'accounts/update'

  #get 'accounts/new'

  # get 'accounts/create'

  # get 'accounts/edit'

  # get 'accounts/destroy'

  # get 'accounts/index'

  # get 'accounts/show'

  # get 'accounts/deposit'

  # get 'accounts/withdrawl'

  #get 'account/new'

  # get 'account/create'

  # get 'account/edit'

  # get 'account/destroy'

  # get 'account/index'

  #  get 'account/show'

  #  get 'account/deposit'

  # get 'account/withdrawl'

  devise_for :users
  get 'admin' => 'admin#index'
  get 'users/index'
  get 'accounts/index'
  get 'accounts/show'

  #get 'accounts/show'


  # resources :accounts

 resources :students

 #controller :sessions do
 #  get 'login' => :new
 #  post 'login' => :create
 #  delete 'logout' => :destroy
  #end

 root 'store#index', as: 'store'


  #get 'sessions/create'

   #get 'sessions/destroy'

   #resources :users

   resources :orders

   resources :line_items

   resources :carts

   get 'store/index'

   resources :menus
   resources :users

   resources :accounts do
     collection do
      post 'deposit', :action => :deposit
      post 'withdrawl', :action => :withdrawl
    end
   end
   # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest
    priority.
   end
```

Comment: When posting code, you should trim irrelevant parts of it ( For example the 20 or so comments out routes)

Answer (score 2):

You should change `return accounts_url` to `redirect_to accounts_url`.

This way you will set the response. The return of the action does not matter.

Comment: i get this after the change Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".

Answer (score 0):

change in your `update` method,

```
return accounts_url
```

to

```
redirect_to accounts_path
```

And remove `respond_with(@account)` line.

Comment: i get this if i do that, Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the call to `respond_with`: that method is already doing a redirect (to the show action for your model)

Then replace your return statement with

```
redirect_to accounts_path
```

While return will of course stop the action doing anything further, the return value is not used.